# execvp() ls no such file or directory

Tags: c, shell, ls

I am writing a shell emulator where if the user types "lsh ls" I would run the command `ls` and ignore the "lsh" that was input by the user. So I am using the readline library to get the input, and then parsing the line. Then I am using fork() and execvp() to run the ls command. However, When I type `lsh ls` I get the following output:

```
lsh: ls: No such file or directory
```

Here is my code. I think it's treating ls as a file to search, but I don't get why it is doing this.

```
int main(){
  pid_t id;
  char* line;
  char **args;
  while(1){
    line = readline("shell: > ");
    if(strcmp(line,"exit") == 0){
        break;
    }
    args = parse(line);
    if(strcmp(args[0],"lsh") == 0){
        id = fork();
        if (id == 0){
            if(execvp(args[1],args) < 0){
                perro("no such command");
            }
        }
        if(id > 0){
            printf("I am the parent process, id %d\n",getppid());
        }
    }   
    free(line);
  }
}
```

Here is the function which parses the line.

```
#define LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define LSH_TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
char **parse(char *line){
   int bufsize = LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
   char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
   char *token;
   if (!tokens) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

  token = strtok(line, " \n");
  while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;

  if (position >= bufsize) {
    bufsize += LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE;
    tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
  if (!tokens) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  }

  token = strtok(NULL, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
  }
  tokens[position] = NULL;
  return tokens;
  free(tokens);
}
```

Comment: Run the executable via strace -f to check what exactly it tries to spawn. Most likely that execvp should be execvp(args[1], args+1).

Comment: What about adding some debug code printing out all of `args`'s elements point to before calling `exec?

Comment: I get args[0] = lsh, args[1] = ls, args[2] = null

Comment: @penatozawa your goal is to skip args[0] altogether, that's why args[1] and args+1. The answer below explains what exactly happens; &args[1] is the same as (args + 1).

Comment: Thank you guys. That fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you see is coming from `ls`, not `lsh`.

You have, in effect:

```
char *args[] = { "lsh", "ls", 0 };

execvp(args[1], args);
```

This means that you attempt to execute `ls`, and do so successfully, but you tell `ls` that it is called `lsh` because `argv[0]` is set to `lsh` and request that it list the file `ls` in the current directory.  So, when `ls` attempts to find the file, it fails, and reports the error using the command name you gave it, `lsh`.

You could try this (the output shown was obtained on macOS Sierra):

```
$ cp /bin/ls xx97
$ ./xx97 23-ish
xx97: 23-ish: No such file or directory
$ rm xx97
```

You need to use:

```
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
```

Then you'll invoke `ls` in an orthodox manner.